# PHP String Pattern Replace

Tags: php, regex

I have a set of strings like this:

```
Pants [+$50]
Shirts [+$10]
Jeans [+$5]
Jackets [+$100]
```

How can I remove the ' [xxx]' in these lines and leaving just the item name (without the trailing space)? I was told to define a regular expression, not sure how that works...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's actually a bit of a confusing regex, since `[` and `]` are special characters:

```
$str = 'Pants [+$50]';
$str = rtrim(preg_replace('/\[[^\]]*\]/', '', $str));

// 'Pants'
```

Basically the partern `\[[^\]]*\]` means to match a literal `[` followed by 0 or more characters that are not `]` followed by a `]`.  The second string in [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) is what it gets replaced with.  In this case the empty string since we want to remove it. Then we use [rtrim](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php) to trim any trailing whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this one:**

*The RegEx*

```
(?im)[ \t]*\[[^\]\[]+\][ \t]*$
```

*Code*

```
$result = preg_replace('/^(.+?)[ \t]*\[[^\][]+\][ \t]*$/im', '$1', $subject);
```